# iMacros error in JS code

Tags: javascript, imacros

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, line NaN (Error code:
>   -991)

I get this error every time I try to use this code in iMacros:

```js
var photo=1;
var macroStart;
macroStart +="CODE:";
macroStart +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macroStart +="TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macroStart +="TAG POS=" +photo+ " TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:fave_photo_inner" + "\n"; 
macroStart +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONCLICK:Photoview.savePhoto()&&ID:pv_save_to_me" + "\n"; 
macroStart +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONCLICK:Photoview.hide(0)&&CLASS:fl_r<SP>pv_close_link" + "\n";

var i=0;
var number=prompt("input number of photos",5);
for (i=1; i <= number; i++)
{
iimPlay(macroStart,25)
iimDisplay("Current image is: "i)
photo++
}

iimDisplay("Success")
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the mistake of missing ‘+’ sign in your line #15. Must be:

```
iimDisplay("Current image is: " + i);
```